# Oracle Apex 5 Checkbox binding

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an apex interactive report and a matching edit form working. I'm trying to add extra column in my database that would bind to a checkbox on a report and a form for each row. The only way of doing that after researching various references seem to be using APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2 in SQL query and selecting graph as column data type. I can render a check box but it is not bound and to save the state I figure I would have to script some code somewhere. Seems to be an awkward way of doing things considering text just binds out of the box. Is there a better way of binding a row level check box in an interactive report, i.e. choosing some specific data type in a database?

Thank you in advance,
Radek

Comment: What would you want to do with that checkbox? Click it, and - as a result - column value (in the database) would change? If so, did you consider switching to Interactive **Grid** instead?

Comment: I tried switching to interactive grid and after I updated the column to the data type checkbox in the grid designer but at run time this checkbox is still rendering as a number instead of checkbox. I figured that this may have something to do with me trying to bind that to a DB column of data type NUMBER(16,2) howerver I don't see Boolean type in the selection. Bottom line I'm not sure if I need to select a specific data type for checkbox to bind automatically to a database column for edits and updates or even if that is possible. Thank you

Comment: Checkbox is *binary* - either it is checked, or it is not. Once you create an interactive grid, navigate to the column you'd want to be a checkbox. On the right hand side of the screen, under column's properties, select "Checkbox" as its type. Then decide what kind of "List of values" will it have (a query, static values, ...) and that should do it. However, as that column is NUMBER(16, 2), I presume it contains a *range* of values - how do you plan to make it a "checkbox"?

Comment: That seem to be the heart of the problem, just learned Oracle doesn't have Boolean data type per say need to use number 1/0 or other types. It seems they only way to do it is to script DB update on checked and unchecked, and controlling the checkbox result in a grid via outputting HTML checkbox tags in a data source query. Will have to play with this bit more as that opens bunch of other question regarding concurrent access and transactions that I still need to figure out. I will try posting a solution if I managed to sort this out.

Comment: Actually, Oracle has Boolean, but only in PL/SQL. In SQL layer, you do have to use number 0/1 or char Y/N or ...